# Stop warnings with summarise

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to know how to stop the warning:

> `summarise() has grouped output by 'Var'. You can override using the .groups argument.`

when I use:

```r
group_by(Var) %>% summarise(...).
```

I would thank any help.

Comment: I think the message is pretty clear in this case?

Comment: Use the `.groups` argument and the warning will go away.

Comment: for these in a hurry `%>%summarise(.groups="keep",.....)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set global option to not display this message by using:

```
options(dplyr.summarise.inform = FALSE)
```

Comment: The warning may be annoying, but it is potentially informative.  I feel a *better* solution is to do as the warning suggests and provide a value for the `.groups` parameter.

Comment: I'd feel better about using the .groups parameter if it weren't an "Experimental" feature.  I try to stick to the mainstream of any programming language I use... and even with this precaution it can still be quite time-consuming to port a "dusty deck" so that it's returning valid results when run on the current "better than ever" version of the language and its libraries!